# Marklogic geojson search

Tags: geospatial, marklogic

MarkLogic newbie here.

How can I search for a Lat/Long point that is within the (multi)polygon below and return the document?

I have thousands of geojson documents and within I have MultiPolygon type geometries like this:

```
"geometry":{  
    "type":"MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates":[  
        [  
            [  
                [  
                    116.761454004,
                    -20.633334001
                ],
                [  
                    116.762183383,
                    -20.633777484
                ],
                            ...
                [  
                    116.761248983,
                    -20.6337970009999
                ],
                [  
                    116.761454004,
                    -20.633334001
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the geospatial region query to match regions. You need to have geospatial region index configured to do so. You can look at the query documentation here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:geospatial-region-query

Comment: Note though that MarkLogic currently doesn't index geojson directly yet. You have to use the [`geojson library`](https://docs.marklogic.com/geojson) to convert to a so-called `cts:region` object, add that to your document, and put your geo index on that instead.